# How to upgrade gsutil if installed via the Cloud SDK

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

My current gsutil version is 4.67. (You can get this by running `gsutil --version`). I wish to upgrade (not update) it to gsutil version 5. How can I do this?

I have used the cloud sdk for my installation and I am not allowed to run `gsutil update`. When I run this, I am prompted to use `gcloud components update`. This will not upgrade my gsutil version.

I am not sure whether I can run `pip3 install gsutil`, because my installation was from the cloud SDK.

Comment: Follow the documentation and install the CLI SDK which includes gsutil. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#sdk-install. Make sure that Python3 is up to date first. You might want to first remove the previous installation of the cloud SDK - your question is not clear on how that was installed. Note: Google Cloud VMs have the CLI preinstalled.

Comment: @JohnHanley might I recommend putting this in an answer? As far as I can tell it is the correct answer; if it isn't, could you, Keet, elaborate on why it isn't?

Comment: @JohnHanley, in the question I have mentioned that "I have used the cloud sdk for my installation". As per your answer, I have to uninstall and reinstall the latest google cloud sdk. I wish the SDK had a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: There are several methods to install the cloud sdk. Clearly showing what you did would have provided good information to help with your problem. The first rule in debugging is to not assume the OP did everything correctly - validate instead.